# Java: How to loop through three List<String>

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, foreach

I have three `List<String>` variables: `classFiles`, `usernames`, and `fileDirectories`. I have a `String` (a list of strings but I will be comparing every string in the list with the loop below) that consists of one item from each of the lists. I want to loop through all three lists and check if one value from all three of the lists are in the String

What would be the best way to go about this?

```
for(String classFile:classFiles) {
//if contains classfile statement
  for(String username:usernames) {
  //if contains username statement
    for(String fileDirectory:fileDirectories) {
      //if contains filedirectory statement
    }
  }
}
```

or

```
for(String classFile:classFiles) {
  for(String username:usernames) {
    for(String fileDirectory:fileDirectories) {
      //if statement
    }
  }
}
```

or

```
for(String classFile:classFiles) {
  //make list of files that contain classFile
}

for(String username:usernames) {
  //remove items from list that do not contain username
}

for(String fileDirectory:fileDirectories){
  //remove items from list that do not contain fileDirectory
}
```

Or is there a better way to do this?

**EDIT: Example**

```
classFiles - a1, a2, a3
usernames - noc1, noc2, noc3
fileDirectories - C:/projects/a1/noc1/example.java, C:/projects/a1/ad3/example.java
```

and the string to check

```
String - C:/bin/a1/noc1/example.class
```

what i want to do is if both the fileDirectory and String contain a classFile and username, then add it to a list

so in this example `C:/bin/a1/noc1/example.class` will be added to the list but `C:/bin/a4/fd1/example.class` wont be or `C:/bin/a3/noc3/example.class` would not be added

Comment: What is the goal of doing the check? To determine what the 3 elements specifically are? A little more context for the problem would help.

Comment: Please consider restating your question with example data. It's not exactly clear what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: The three type of repeated operation you are trying on lists, are they totally unrelated? If this is the case then all the three approaches will have same performance (O(n)).

Comment: why you dont want to do 'if(classFiles.contains(string)) //do sth' ?

Comment: @Santosh The first two are O(n^3).

Comment: @NathanielFord You are right. I meant the best performance that can be had if operations are unrelated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you perform remove operations for-each loop is not best choice. You should use Iterator and remove on iterator to avoid concurrent modification exception.

Instead

```
for(String fileDirectory:fileDirectories){
  //remove items from list that do not contain fileDirectory
}
```

You should do something like

```
Iterator iter = fileDirectores.iterator();
while(iter.hasNext())
{
//Get next
//Do your check 
iter.remove();
}
```

This leads to having three separate iterates to full fill your requirement.

Comment: so would this be the best way of going about what I am trying to do or what would be the best way?

Comment: Yes, I feel this would be best/safe approach.

Comment: yes i used iterators and after a bit of work i got it going... cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

It is sometimes best to define the function you're actually trying to write:

```
/**
  * Checks to see if candidate has one string in each of classFiles, usernames and fileDirectories
  */ 
public boolean hasEssentialComponents(List<String> candidate) {
  //Code here
}
```

Now, your first option has a very long maximum run time O(n^3). If you expect the function to generally fail what it means is that for each item in your three lists you are looping through the next list. Most of this is redundant, and you will have a huge performance impact if these lists are long.

The second one is subtly different, but with the same total runtime.

The third is clearly better; in this you can fail as soon as you find out that a list doesn't have a component and you never check a list for a component twice. However, Java provides some [sugar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/) that can make this easier.

```
public boolean hasEssentialComponents(List<String> candidates) {
  //Sanity check the data
  if (candidate.size() != 3) { return false; } //I'm assuming a 'good' candidate has only three items.

  valid = true;
  for (String candidate:candidates) {
    if (valid &&  
        ! (   check(this.classFiles, candidate)
           || check(this.usernames, candidate)
           || check(this.fileDirectories, candidate) )
          )) {
      valid = false;
    }
  }
  return valid;
}

private boolean check(List<String> masterList, String candidate) {
  return masterList.contains(candidate);
}
```

Now, I'm being unnecessarily verbose here to make sure to tease out the parts of the problem. Please note that you should use Java built in functions when possible; they're well optimized. Do not add your lists together; you're spending unnecessary time copying. Also, make each comparison only once if that is all you need: note that if you know where element in your string list should be in one of your master lists, this can be made even better.

Finally, I really recommend you write out a method signature first. It forces you to think about what you're actually trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

So I take it you want to get the intersection between all three lists?
Just use the `retainAll` method on List.

```
classFiles.retainAll(usernames);
classFiles.retainAll(fileDirectories);
```

Now `classFiles` will just have the intersection between all three lists.

Comment: I don't think that's what he's going for. As I understood the question, there's actually a 4th list - a list of strings, where each element of that list has several substrings. He wants to compare those substrings to the 3 lists of 'options'.

Comment: yes bfishmam is correct. I want to check if for each element of the 4th list, that element contains a string from each of the other 3 lists

Answer (score 0):

Can you consider to use a HashSet or HashMap to access quickly your string value (with .contains(string))?

It will eliminates the loops.

I would do this way if I understand well the problem (not sure^^)